# Is action synchronized when the getter is too?

Tags: java, synchronized, getter

If I have a class which has a `Map` named `myMap` and a getter :

```
public Map getMap() {
    synchronized(myMap) {
        return myMap;
    }
}
```

Is `getMap().put(Something)` will be synchronized too ?

Comment: nope… that's a different operation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  The only thing here that is synchronized is the calling of the method to get the instance of that map.  Operations on that map are not synchronized (if they aren't backed by a [synchronized implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)) of a map).